# Make a custom scoreboard as a datapack for my server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I have a server where I host hide and seek games from time to time, where I'd like to show a scoreboard that shows the players' names, if they're a seeker or not (based on their team), how many seekers there currently are, how many hiders are left, and the remaining time.

So like this:

```
- Hide and Seek    (as the name of the scoreboard)

- [PlayerName]

- You are a
- [Seeker/Hider]

- Seekers            X

- Hiders remaining   X
```

I already have the Hider and Seeker teams, and a datapack that turns a hider into a seeker when they are hit by a seeker.

I currently have 5 files that change the hider into a seeker when hit:

- `hit_by_seeker.mcfunction`:

  ```
  advancement revoke @s only hit_by_seeker:hit_by_seeker
  team join Seekers @s
  ```
- `hit_hider.mcfunction`:

  ```
  advancement revoke @s only hit_by_seeker:hit_hider`
  `team join Hiders @s`
  ```
- `swap.mcfunction`:

  ```
  team join Hiders @a[tag=Hiders] 
  team join Seekers @a[tag=Seekers] 
  tag @a remove Hiders 
  tag @a remove Seekers
  ```
- `hit_by_seeker.json`:

  ```
  {
    "criteria": {
      "requirement": {
        "trigger": "minecraft:entity_hurt_player",
        "conditions": {
          "player": {
            "team": "Hiders"
          },
          "damage": {
            "source_entity": {
              "type": "player",
              "team": "Seekers"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "rewards": {
      "function": "hit_by_seeker:hit_by_seeker"
    }
  }
  ```
- `hit_hider.json`:

  ```
  {
    "criteria": {
      "requirement": {
        "trigger": "minecraft:player_hurt_entity",
        "conditions": {
          "player": {
            "team": "Seekers"
          },
          "entity": {
            "type": "player",
            "team": "Hiders"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "rewards": {
      "function": "hit_by_seeker:hit_hider"
    }
  }
  ```

I have tried to use a couple plugins but those didn't seem to match my expectations.

I would like to know how to make a scoreboard using these teams and this datapack.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet tbh, cause I really have no idea how to start this. But i have a button that sets all players to hiders and then a random player to seeker.